# Why printing arrays of characters gives garbled characters?

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop

I'm reading characters into an array and try to print them out. The code is given below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define N 50

int read_message(char a[], int n)
{
    char ch;
    int i = 0;

    printf("Enter a message: ");
    for (i = 0; (ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n'; i++) {
        if (toupper(ch) >= 'A' && toupper(ch) <= 'Z') {
            a[i] = tolower(ch);
        }
    }

    return i;
}

void print_message(char a[], int n)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%c", a[i]);

    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    char message[N];
    int message_len = read_message(message, N);

    print_message(message, message_len);
}
```

When I enter "He h", it shows "he蘦".

However, if I change the `read_message()` in the following way, the problem is solved.

```
int read_message(char a[], int n)
{
    char ch;
    int i = 0;

    printf("Enter a message: ");
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n') {
        if (toupper(ch) >= 'A' && toupper(ch) <= 'Z') {
            a[i] = tolower(ch);
            i++;
        }
    }

    return i;
}
```

I heard that `for` and `while` are equivalent, so I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: The [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) function returns an **`int`**, which is very important when comparing to the `int` value `EOF`.

Comment: And please use the standard [`isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) function instead of comparing yourself.

Comment: getchar() returns a an int (EOF Is usually -1; char might be unsigned).

Comment: As for your problem, explain to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) the two different `read_message` functions. Concentrate on when and where the value of `i` is updated.

Comment: "I heard that for and while are equivalent...." Well, only if you do it correct. And you don't. This: `for(i = 0; CONDITION; i++) { DO_YOUR_WORK; }` is equivalent to `i = 0; while( CONDITION ){ DO_YOUR_WORK; i++; }` but that is not what your code is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first version of `read_message()` you have the following issues:

1. `int ch` as `getchar()` returns an `int` (on my system char is unsigned and EOF defined as -1).
2. Only increment `i` when you have a valid letter which is in the `if` body not for each iteration of the loop.
3. `a` should be `\0`-terminate.
4. `a` is subject to overflows (`i + 1 >= n`).
5. (minor) prefer unsigned types for length (`unsigned`, `size_t` etc).
6. (minor) Use `isalpha()` just because it's cleaner than the two `toupper()` calls.  Letters are stored in lower case so it's strange that we compare the range in upper case. Other locales may have a different alphabet.
7. (minor and not fixed to minimize change) replace `for` with `while` as it now has neither initialization or increment parts (this would be case even if it was `for (i=0; ...)` just easier to see this way).

```
unsigned read_message(char a[], unsigned n) {
    printf("Enter a message: ");
    int ch;
    unsigned i = 0;
    for (; (ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n' && i + 1 < n;) {
        if (isalpha(ch)) {
            a[i++] = tolower(ch);
        }
    }
    if(n)
        a[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

I would swap the arguments so you can document the relationship between `n` and `a`, and write it like this (as @Lundin wasn't a fan of the above):

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdin.h>

#define N 50

size_t read_message(size_t n, char a[n]) {
   printf("Enter a message: ");
   size_t i = 0;
   while(i + 1 < n) {
       int ch = getchar();
       if(ch == EOF || ch == '\n') break;
       if(!isalpha(ch)) continue;
       a[i++] = tolower(ch);
   }
   if(n) a[i] = '\0';
   return i;
}

int main() {
    char s[N];
    size_t n = read_message(sizeof(s), s);
    printf("%u, %s\n", n, s);
}
```

and example execution:

```
Enter a message: Hello WoRLD 123 how Are You?
19, helloworldhowareyou
```

Comment: I'll refrain from down-voting since you point out a lot of problems in the code, but that is one truly horrible loop. We should not teach or encourage beginners to write crap like that. I posted an answer with a simplified version of it.

Answer (score 2):

As a follow up to another answer:

Please for the love of obfuscation never write obscure loops such as
`for (; (ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n' && i + 1 < n;)`
Contrary to popular belief, most operators on a single line does *not* win a price. It might cause you to lose your C programmer job, however...

This code should be de-obfuscated into something readable, using the most canonical form of a `for` loop (`for(int i=0; i<n; i++)`) if that is possible:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  int ch = getchar();
  if(ch == EOF || ch == '\n')
  { 
    break; 
  }

  if(isalpha(ch))
  {
    a[i] = tolower(ch);
  }
}
```

Notes:

- `isalpha` tests for any character for which `isupper` or `islower` is true. Whereas `tolower` converts any character for which `isupper` is true. So you may as well use `isupper`, or even skip the `if` and just do `a[i] = tolower(ch)`.
- In case you only want to increase the counter when a certain condition is true, you need a separate counter variable. Do *not* obfuscate the for loop by moving `i++` out of the 3rd clause of the `for`.

Overall, your code could be simplified a lot and there's no obvious need to keep track of the string length manually in this case. You could simplify the whole thing to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define N 50

void read_message (char a[], int n)
{
    int i;

    printf("Enter a message: ");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
      int ch = getchar();
      if(ch == EOF || ch == '\n')
      { 
        break; 
      }
      a[i] = tolower(ch);
    }
    a[i] = '\0';
}

int main (void)
{
    char message[N+1];
    read_message(message, N);
    puts(message);
}
```

Input:

```
Hello WoRLD 123 how Are You?
```

Output:

```
hello world 123 how are you?
```

Comment: You are solving a different problem, no? Op only wants letters and store them in lower case. Break is cleaner, and I would probably have used that.  Your code writes the '\0' out of bounds (at a[n]); I made the same mistake initially.

Comment: @AllanWind Well only letters is a simple thing to fix and the OP can make _some_ effort into tweaking the code themselves. As for the out of bounds, I guess it's about specifying if `n` is meant to mean the string length or array length. Fixed.

Comment: Your fix is the better way.  By "solving a different problem" I just mean that your case, for your code being cleaner than mine, could be stronger.